# getting data from python script on webserver using swift

Tags: python, swift

I have a python script on my webserver which simply prints out 2 to 5 words, one under the other.

```
Ruyterplaats
Civic Centre
Racecourse
Atlantis
```

What I need to do is the following:

- open the url www.webserveraddress.com?variable1=variable2
- get the words from each line and put them into an array

No need to display the webpage, I just need the words. Thats all.

Iv seen I can use things like Libxml2 and Hpple, but these are ObjC wrappers around other code. I'm not sure how Swift will cope with that.

I quite frankly have no idea where to start or even if I'm going about it the wrong or not :/

PS. I would post code but the python script is around 6500 lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get the contents of a URL as a string is to use the [constructor on NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL%3a):

```
var contents = NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com"), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Then you can separate the contents into an array using [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet%3a):

```
var wordArray = contents.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
```

**Note**: The server side technology doesn't matter at all, which is one of the best things about the HTTP protocol ;). That URl could return a static file for all the Swift code (or anyone else) will care.